# How to disable android archive functionality on flutter application?

Tags: android, flutter, archive, google-play-console

[image: I have warning in play console that says]

So I need to disable this archive feature but can't I don't know from where.

I tried this in `build.gradle`, but it didn't work.

```
bundle {
    storeArchive.enable = false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AGP 7.2 or newer and want to opt-out of the generation of archived APKs, you can modify the build.gradle file of the project:

```
android {
    bundle {
        storeArchive {
            enable = false
        }
    }
}
```

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/freeing-up-60-of-storage-for-apps.html

Comment: What are the risks of using this feature please ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your AGP version first. If it's lower than 7.2 (flutter by default use 4.1) you have to use different approach that described here — https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/freeing-up-60-of-storage-for-apps.html

As it mentioned there:

> For older Bundletool and AGP versions you can opt-out by including an
> opt-out file in your resources:
> res/xml/com_android_vending_archive_opt_out.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<optOut />
```